# MVC3 - Preserve 'returnUrl' after a postback?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm coding a login function for my site. When a user requests a view that is restricted with my `[CustomAuthorize]` attribute, the user is rightfully redirected to the `/Login/Index` view with the query string appended (`?ReturnUrl=%2fRestricted%2fView`).

**But here's the problem...**

When a user tries to login, and there's a validation error. The post request causes a postback (duh), and the appended query string disappears from the Url.

- How can I preserve the query string after a postback?

**CustomAuthorize.cs:**

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
        protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
            if (httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                var customIdentity = (CustomIdentity)httpContext.User.Identity;
                var customPrincipal = new CustomPrincipal(customIdentity);

                if (customIdentity.IsAdmin)
                {
                    httpContext.User = customPrincipal;
                    Thread.CurrentPrincipal = customPrincipal;
                }
            }
            return base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
        }

        protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            var urlRequested = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Path;
            //urlRequested contains "/Restricted/View"
            //Do something with 'urlRequested' here, or?
            base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
        }
}
```

**Login/Index view:**

```
<body>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Login"))
        {
            <div>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName)
            </div>
            <div>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName)
            </div>

            <div>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password)
            </div>
            <div>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
            </div>

            <div>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RememberMe)
            </div>
            <div>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RememberMe)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RememberMe)
            </div>

            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Login!" />
            </p>
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        }
</body>
```

**Login/Index controller action:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(LoginModelBinding login, string returnUrl)
{
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (Service.CheckUser(login.UserName, login.Password))
                {
                    String loginError;
                    CustomAuthorization.Login(login.UserName, login.Password, out loginError);

                    if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
                    {
                        return Redirect(returnUrl);
                    }
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "MitTeam");

                }
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "The entered user name or password is incorrect");
            }
            return View(login);
}
```

**SOLUTION:**
As per Naveen's answer I modified the code like this:

```
public static void SaveReturnUrl(this Controller controller, string returnUrl, bool showAfterRedirect = true)
{
            if (showAfterRedirect)
            {
                controller.TempData["returnUrl"] = returnUrl;
            }
            else
            {
                controller.ViewData["returnUrl"] = returnUrl;
            }
}

public static string RetrieveReturnUrl(this Controller controller)
{
            var message = controller.ViewData.ContainsKey("returnUrl") ? controller.ViewData["returnUrl"] : controller.TempData.ContainsKey("returnUrl") ? controller.TempData["returnUrl"] : null;
            return message as string;
}
```

With these two extension methods I can save and retrieve the returnurl in my Login Controller method/action.

**Login post method:**

```
var previousReturnUrl = this.RetrieveReturnUrl();
if(!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(previousReturnUrl))
    {
        this.SaveReturnUrl(returnUrl);
    }
    return View(login);
}
```

And if the modelstate is valid, i just call `this.RetrieveReturnUrl` and decode it, so I can redirect the user in the event of a successful login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the code module developed by [Martijn Boland](http://blogs.taiga.nl/martijn/) - [Keep your users informed](http://blogs.taiga.nl/martijn/2011/05/03/keep-your-users-informed-with-asp-net-mvc/). It can be used to store any object and fetch it back after a redirect. It was specifically used to show the message or status of the operation after a POST-REDIRECT operation. This works for AJAX types of requests too.

You may use the same for the storing the return URL along with the message (incase of auth failure) after making a redirect.

Comment: Thank you! `ViewContext.TempData` helped me alot! Will edit my question with my solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the returnURL in your view in a hidden field. As long as you include that hidden field in the form that ist posted back to the server, your POST-Action can access and use it depending on the outcome of the Action (login successful -> redirect to url, login unsuccessful -> return the login view with the hidden field again).

Comment: I have to return the View once again, with the model `LoginModelBinding` in order to show the validation errors on the page. If I just redirect to the returnurl, or redirect to the same View with RouteValuesDictionary then no validation errors are shown.